# Toggle checkbox value

Tags: jquery

Toggling checkbox values is not working. When click on the checkbox, the value for the input field is set to 1. When I click again the value should be blank

```
<div class="GruppoCheck">
<input type="checkbox" value="1"/>

</div>
<div id="checkMonitor"></div>
<div id="checkMonitorNUMBER"></div>
<div id="test"></div>
```

JS:

```
var CheckFUN = function() {
    var numberCheckedVAR = $('input:checkbox:checked').length;

    var $checkMonitor = $('#checkMonitor').empty();
    $('.GruppoCheck :checkbox:checked').each(function(index) {
        if(index == 0){
            $checkMonitor.append($(this).val());
            var val = $(this).val();
        }
        $('#test').html('<input type="text" id="testi" value="'+val+'"> ');

    }); 
}

$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    CheckFUN();
});
```

Comment: What is checkMonitor element?

Comment: Please check this http://jsfiddle.net/w5dqq6us/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know if a checkbox is checked you don't have to use value, but `checked` prop; in your case your code can become simpler by using `length` property.

Code:

```
var totChk=$('.GruppoCheck :checkbox:checked').length;
$('#test').html('<input type="text" id="testi" value="' + totChk + '"> ');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/w5dqq6us/1/